# Compose BottomSheetScaffold content insets

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I'm using BottomSheetScaffold to display bottom sheet where sheetContent can change it's height. Bottom Sheet behaves correctly and when content changes height also changes.

My question is regarding
`content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit`

I'd like to use padding values to correctly set column with verticalScroll to display all items on top of open bottom sheet.
For now PaddingValues are calculated once, and don't change for next rebuilds.

Or maybe there's other way that I should use to place content on top of bottom sheet?